# Zend mail code in my php code?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I've got some php code handling emails (not self written) which I want to integrate in my own self written system. In it, two Classes are used:

- Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3($params)
- Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($params)

I've heard of Zend before, but as far as I know it is some kind of full fledged php framework, not something I really what to incorporate in my system just to be able to use these two classes. So I downloaded Zend from [the github page](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2), but I can't even find those classes in there.

So my questions are:

1. Am I able (and if so, how?) to just use these two classes from Zend?
2. If not, is there an alternative to these two classes which are preferably very easy to use?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing exactly what you want to do (you've just said what classes you think might achieve that goal), but hopefully I can point you in the right direction.

Zend Framework is a full PHP framework, but it was built as a collection of libraries, and to a certain extent you can just cherry pick individual components and only use those. The two classes you listed were from Zend Framework 1. What you downloaded from Github was Zend Framework 2, which is why you can't find them, but ZF2 does have equivalents.

Although you could download ZF1 and get your existing code to work, what I'd suggest you do instead is add just the [ZF2 Mail component](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendMail) to your app using Composer. Then start here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mail.read.html for the docs for the equivalent classes for what I'm guessing you're trying to do.